What property of $C^{\infty}(M)$ guarentees that finitely generated module self-dual?
According to Serre–Swan theorem the category of smooth vector bundles on a smooth manifold $M$ is equivalent to the category of finitely generated, projective $C^{\infty}(M)$-modules, and note that any vector bundle isomorphic to its dual, so any finitely generated, projective $C^{\infty}(M)$  module will be self-dual.
I think self-duality is not true for arbitrary rings(although in general case finitely generated, projective implies isomorphic to its double dual), but I don't have an example(please tell me if you know one). What special property of $C^{\infty}(M)$ guarantees finitely generated projective modules over it are selfdual? (maybe this relies only on that in $C^\infty(M)$ there is partition of unity$1=\sum_jf_j$?)
To avoid confusion: A $R$ module $M$ is said to be self-dual here if $M\cong \text{hom}_R(M,R)$

I think that OP asks about finitely generated modules being self-dual, which is not automatic (and fails for eg number rings)?

sorry for the ambiguity

Means it isomorphic to its dual

@Aphelli: Could you give a reference for f.g. Projective module over number rings not selfdual?

Invertible modules over the ring of integers $R$ of a number field $K$ are self-dual iff the class group of $R$ is killed by $2$ (this is elementary). The LMFDB gives you plenty of $R$ where this isn’t the case (you can also look for genus theory of imaginary quadratic fields, see eg Cox’s book).
